# Can I edit the Navbar from react-bootstrap module ? How to do it?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm currently trying to make web app using react-bootstrap and I wanted to change some of the navbar element from react-bootstrap module using CSS. I want to change the color, font size, etc. for the nav.link tag how can I do it ?

Here's my Header.JS code:

```
import {Navbar, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../CSS/Header.css'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <Navbar className="MainHeader" expand="lg" variant="dark">
            <>
                <Navbar.Brand className="Headerlogo" as={Link} to={"/"}>
                    <img src="/Images/logowhite.png" alt="hotel_logo"/>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse className="Headerlist justify-content-end fontReg">
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/Facilities"}>Facilities</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/Room"}>Room</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/Events"}>Events</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/Contactus"}>Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/Booknow"}>Book Now</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: Yes, there is className property also you can add classes and style them as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css. Add class to your element

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/Facilities"} className="custom-link"> ...
```

Then in your Header.css file

```css
.custom-link {
  color: #F5890;
  font-size: 20px;
  ...
}
```